# Disabling tagged values from traced elements in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am working on creating traceability between requirements,class and test case elements in Enterprise Architect (version 12.1) using the realisation connector.

I am facing issue with the tagged value window. Here all the tagged values of elements to which traceability is established is listed (hierarchically).

I have 30 requirements and each of this are mapped to 40 class/interface elements.

Every time I try to open the element properties or view tagged value window or even select the element, the window is loaded with the tagged value of all the traced elements and this is causes huge delay in opening tagged values window /element properties and I am facing difficult in updating a single tagged value also. EA also ends up in not responding state sometimes.

I understand from here : https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/modeling_tools/advancedtagmanagement.html that tagged value hierarchy is provided in EA.

I also tried to search for option to disable these tagged values from being displayed in Tools --> Options --> Objects , yet unable to find any.

Please suggest me any option to disable this feature so that only tagged values of the selected element is displayed. This will greatly help me in working with large size files with traceability.
[image: trace window]
[image: tagged value window]

Answer (score 2):

This is due to your Realize relation which inherits tagged values as well. Consider using a `<<trace>>` dependency instead.